# How to select parent rows, whose children contain a set of subvalues?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to select rows from images where the set of tags belonging to an image contains at least all of the tags specified in a list of strings.

```
CREATE TABLE images (
                        image_checksum varchar(56) NOT NULL,
                        filename varchar(56),
                        PRIMARY KEY (image_checksum)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
                      id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      name varchar(64),
                      confidence DECIMAL(5,2),
                      image varchar(56) NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id),
                      FOREIGN KEY (image) REFERENCES images(image_checksum)
);
```

I have this query that returns all of the images with tags that contain ANY of the objects specified in the list. The list will be variable length depending on what comes in from the client. I have two images in my database specified. One of a dog, one of a cat. With the query I need -- I would expect to get zero results because neither image contains a dog AND a cat.

```
SELECT DISTINCT images.image_checksum, images.filename, tags.name, tags.confidence from images 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON (tags.image = images.image_checksum)
WHERE name in ('dog','cat');
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: IN clause is equal to or, so use and for both

Comment: I'm not following, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want window functions to count the number of matching tags.  Then use that for filtering:

```
SELECT it.*
FROM (SELECT i.image_checksum, i.filename, t.name, tags.confidence ,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i.image_checksum) as num_tags
      FROM images i JOIN
           tags t
           ON t.image = i.image_checksum
      WHERE t.name in ('dog', 'cat')
     ) it
WHERE num_tags = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use group_concat for this particular problem.

```
SELECT images.image_checksum, images.filename, tags.name, 
       tags.confidence
  from images 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON (tags.image = images.image_checksum)
 WHERE tags.image in (select t1.image
                        from tags t1
                       group by t1.image
                      having group_concat(t1.name order by t1.name asc) like '%cat,dog%');
```

This will return all images that have both tags, but will also return all the tags related to those images.

You would have to just make sure that the tags being searched are in alphabetical order, so that it may find them.

group_concat, by default, uses a comma as a separator for different values.

But, it can be overridden using the key word SEPARATOR

```
group_concat(tags.name SEPARATOR ', ')
```

More info can be obtained [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)